# Another linear layout with a button not appearing

Tags: java, android

i made another linear layout beside the first one by your help, but now after trying to add a new button in the left the button is not appearing even though i made wrap_content as i learned but still it's not appearing while the buttons in the first linearlayout are working perfectly i hope you can help and thanks

this is the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="اضغط على من تريد معرفة المزيد عنه"
android:padding="10dp"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttontype1"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Start" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Start" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Stop"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button3"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Start" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button4"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:text="Stop" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button5"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Start" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button6"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Stop"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button7"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Start" />


<Button
android:id="@+id/button8"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Stop"/>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonkk"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:text="HII"/>

</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And where is that `RelativeLayout` you are talking about supposed to be? Because it is not in the layout you posted.

Comment: sorry i meant another linearlayout* its there at the end with the last button

Comment: I just literally copied your layout and it is working perfectly for me. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: its working but the last button is not appearing in the left notice that

Comment: It is for me. And I don't see anything that could possibly be wrong with that layout. It's 100% fine. Are you sure the `Button` is not just beyond the borders of your screen?

Comment: what do u mean by beyond the borders?

Comment: How far down are the other `Buttons` going? Do they reach the end of the screen at the bottom?

Comment: yes the last button is is at the end with the other linearlayout

Comment: Well if the other `Buttons` - the ones with the text "STOP" - are reaching all the way down to the end of your screen where do you think the last button might be? Somewhere beyond the end of the screen, put everything in a scrollview or trim down the height of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything inside a ScrollView

Comment: i did and it now appears but when i set the gravity to the left its not going there

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve please? I can help you with that. BTW if that was the answer to your question can you mark it as an answer? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to set all your button with value `android:layout_weight="1"`
It allows you to achieve proportional distribution of elements within a LinearLayout.

Read that : http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/

Comment: i did everything and it does appear now but the problem is when i set the gravity to the left it doesn't go to the left

Comment: Maybe you should use RelativeLayout ? Because it allows you to place all yours view relative from eachother. An other way it's to set your width and height on wrap_content